# Autoplay help Javascript and Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want my VibeDeck script to autoplay. It uses an href="#play" line in HTML to call it once clicked on.

But the problem is, I have tried getting the Parent window to redirect to #play. As well as the actual iframe window to redirect to #play. But it still wont play on its own. I really would like to know if there is any way to call on the play function automatically for this script. It is currently located at

http://12-3.co.uk/

It is the playlist at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an `onLoad="functionYouCallToStartPlaying()"` attribute to your site's body tag.

Or:

```
<script>
function checkIfDefaultPage(pageAddress)
{
   //basically check if the user is on the homepage and you have no #play in the URL, 
   //so the URL does not become http://12-3.co.uk/#play#play
   if((pageAddress == "http://12-3.co.uk")||(pageAddress == "http://12-3.co.uk/")) 
      return true;
   return false;
}

function jsRedirect()
{
   if(checkIfDefaultPage(Document.Location))
        Document.Location = Document.Location + "#play";
}
</script>
```

while having

```
<body onLoad="jsRedirect();">
```

This might make the JavaScript redirect work for you.

EDIT: Inspiration for avoiding Document.Location problem where you might redirect multiple times is located [here](http://forum.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=65482).

Comment: I've tried that, But the problem is, is the code is difficult to find their functions. I have no clue what function is used to play.

Comment: Thanks! I think this might work , But anotehr issue is that the frame itself uses Javascript to call onto another script located on a different site. And that Javascript calls onto an iFrame location to place into the frame. Is there any way I can get this to work with that?

Comment: What do you mean by "calls onto an iFrame location to place into the frame"? If the target on the link you normally use to start playing is the iframe itself, you can adapt the code above to get the iframe's element (say... give it a name for easy retrieval and use Document.getElementsByName('iframeName') to get it), then append "#play" to the iframe's src attribute.